# CNTK: Python vs C# API for model consumption

Tags: cntk

We have trained a model using CNTK. We are building a service that is going to load  this model and respond to requests to classify sentences. What is the best API to use regarding performance? We would prefer to build a C# service as in https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/Evaluation/CSEvalClient but alternatively we are considering building a Python service that is going to load the model in python.

Do you have any recommendations towards one or the other approach? (regarding which API is faster, actively maintained or other parameters you can think of). The next step would be to set up an experiment measuring the performance of both API calls, but was wondering if there is some prior knowledge here that could help us decide.

Thank you

Comment: This question might be better suited in Stack Exchange's Software Engineering. http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ -- I usually refer to this when the lines blur: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/309337

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both APIs are well developed/maintained. For text data I would go with the C# API.

In C# the main focus is fast and easy evaluation and for text loading the data is straightforward.

The Python API is good for development/training of models and at this time not much attention has been paid to evaluation. Furthermore, because of the wealth of packages loading data in exotic formats is easier in Python than C#.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see here https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/EvalDLL-Evaluation-Overview the following: "Single threaded evaluation
The CNTK evaluation library, and by extension the managed EvalWrapper library, are single threaded and single re-entrancy. That means that a single model can only be evaluated by a single thread at a time. However, it is possible to load multiple models in the same process and query each model using a single thread." Does the single thread limitation apply to the python evaluation API?

Comment: I am sorry apparently there are two different C# evaluation APIs based on here: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Evaluation-Overview I am interested in support of evaluation of multiple requests in parallel by multi-threading but it seems it is not possible in C# (under development)

Answer (score 2):

The new C# Eval API based on CNTKLibrary will be available very soon (the first beta is probably next week). This API has functional parity with the C++ and Python API regarding evaluation.

This API supports using multiple threads to serve multiple evaluation requests in parallel, and even better, model parameters of the same loaded model is shared between these threads, which will significantly reduce memory usage in a service environment.

We have also a [turorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Evaluate-a-model-in-an-Azure-WebApi) about how to use Eval API in ASP.Net environment. It still refers to EvalDLL evaluation, but applies to the new C# API too. The document will be updated after the new C# API is released.